# Lost the ability to paste images into posts from clipboard

Tags: bug, images

It could just be me or my setup, but I seem to have lost the ability to paste images from the clipboard into posts via the *Add Image* tool.  Anyone else?

I know that Chrome recently had an update, but the same thing also seems to be true with Safari.

Tell me I'm not going crazy....

In fact, the dialog box now no longer gives **"or paste"** before the drag-and-drop option, either:

[image]

This is directly contrary to the [recent answer / screenshot given over at meta.SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231260)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed for about a month now, working on [WebKit-based browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based).

Comment: That's quite unfortunate...

Comment: @cslstr: Agreed. [I'm hoping there's some change that will be implemented on SE's side](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63516/add-support-for-pasting-images/231260#comment764714_231260). I don't really know, but *loved* that feature!

Comment: I asked about "expanding this to other browsers" a while back: [Why is paste/drag-and-drop of images not available on some browsers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188656/168244) As of now, all seems lost. :(

Comment: Equivalent discussion on Meta.SE: [Has pasting images directly into the upload box been dropped? Or is it just me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232417/168244)

Comment: @cslstr: This capability to copy-and-paste images has been restores in Chrome (and other browsers).